# Prove that the solution x(t) goes to infinity in finite time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help with the following:
Prove that the solution $x(t)$ of the scalar system $\dot x(t) = e^{x(t)}-1$, with $x(0)=1$ goes to infinity in finite time.

I get that the solution $ x(t) = -\ln[1-e^{t-1}(e-1)] \rightarrow \infty$ as $t \rightarrow \ln\bigg[\dfrac{e}{e-1}\bigg]$, and can show that, but I am generally bad at proofs and don't really ever understand how to start them.

I would greatly appreciate help with this proof and/or tips on the logic/thought process to use when trying to prove something.

Thanks,

Thomas

Comment: In my experience, "time" is taken to be a parameter $t \in [0, \infty)$. Hence, you just need to show that there exists a $t_{0} \in [0, \infty)$ such that $x(t) \to \infty$ as $t \to t_{0}$. You claim to have already done this.

Comment: So I've plugged in $t_0=ln \bigg[\dfrac{e}{e-1}\bigg]$ to the solution $x(t)$ and shown that the result is $x(t_0)=\infty$. Does this qualify as a proof?

Comment: You can't plug $t_{0}$ into $x$ because the result is undefined. A better way to do it would be to show that as $t$ gets closer and closer to $t_{0}$ from below, then $x(t)$ gets larger than any finite number. In other words, show that, for all $M \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $t \in (t_{0} - \delta, t_{0}) \implies $x(t) > M$.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, basically I need to show that for any arbitrarily large number $M$ having a $t$ arbitrarily close to $t_0$ results in $x(t)>M$, correct? What I'm bad at is the show part. Do I need to show that the solution is not lipchitz or something?

Answer (score 0):

You are asked to prove two things: that $x(t)$ is a solution, and that it goes to infinity in finite time.

The first may be the most intimidating part, but it's actually the easiest. What's the nicest way of to show something satisfies an equation? You just plug it in! Doesn't matter if it's scalar-valued ($x^2 + 3x - 4 = 0$) or function-valued ($\dot{x}(t) = e^{x(t)} - 1$). So just plug in your solution (taking care to verify that it's differentiable), and you've got the first part done.

The second part is just a limit proof, and you claim that you can show that already. So you're done!

---

The real hard part about proofs like this is finding the solution in the first place. Since all you need to do for the proof is to plug it in and check, you don't have to be especially formal when you find the solution. Do that part however you find most natural! (Well, as long as it's correct...)

Comment: I don't think I actually did a limit proof. I just noticed that as $e^{t-1}(e-1)\rightarrow 1$ then $x(t)\rightarrow-ln(1-1)=-ln(0)$ which is undefined but technically $\infty$?